# Call function at interval of 5 seconds then 4 seconds then 3 etc

Tags: java, android

I have a function `foo()`.

I want to call `foo()` every 5 seconds, and after "X" calls of `foo()` call it every 4 seconds. After another "X" calls of `foo()` every 3 seconds until foo is called every second.

I also need to be able to stop calling foo at anytime.

I have looked through other Stack Overflow posts and have not found anything that allows me to change the interval of calling dynamically.

What can I do?

Comment: You would get better help, if you can show the codes you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `Timer`and `TimerTask` classes in Java. You can schedule a TimerTask and have the task decide when it is scheduled the next time. The task schedules itself.

This way you can dynamically decide for the next execution interval.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {

    public interface FooService {
        public void foo();
    }

    public static class DelayCalculator {
        public long nextTime() { // ... };
    }
    public static class FooTask extends TimerTask {

        FooService fooSvc;

        public FooTask(FooService foos) {
            fooSvc = foos;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            fooSvc.foo();

            TIMER.schedule(new FooTask(fooSvc), DELAYCALC.nextTime());
        }
    }

    private static final Timer TIMER = new Timer();

    private static final DelayCalculator DELAYCALC = new DelayCalculator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooTask fooT = new FooTask(() -> System.out.println("Foo"));
        TIMER.schedule(fooT, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer (either via Alarm of Handler) for every 5 seconds.  Keep a track of how many times its been called.  When that number is higher than X, change the timer to every 4 seconds.  When its higher than 2*X, change it to 3.  Etc.